# how To turn an json object to table of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, object

i used to push a data into array but the data was like bellow can some one tell me how to turn this object to arrray of object

```
d2 = {
      {
        id: "BK1",
        type: "MAGE",
        role: "DARK"
      },
      {
        id: "BK1",
        type: "MAGE",
        role: "DARK"
      },
      {
        id: "BK1",
        type: "MAGE",
        role: "DARK"
      }
    }
```

to this how i want it to look like:

```
d2 = [
      {
        id: "BK1",
        type: "MAGE",
        role: "DARK"
      },
      {
        id: "BK1",
        type: "MAGE",
        role: "DARK"
      },
      {
        id: "BK1",
        type: "MAGE",
        role: "DARK"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: The first code you posted is invalid in javascript (it is also not a valid json string or parsed json string), it looks like you already have an array.

Comment: Source object is not a valid one

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for ... in` loop to iterate over the keys within the object and push those onto an array:

```
const transformedD2 = [];

for (const key in d2) {
  transformedD2.push(d2[key]);
}
```

You could also use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

The thing is, the object you included as an example isn't valid, as briosheje has pointed out. It only has values, no keys.